# FLUTTER ERROR sdkmanager error!!! Windows 10

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, error-handling

AndroidStudio is updated everything is updated I think error come from here C:\Users\lanet\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager because this folder couldnt created when I looked to there I'm waiting for advises . thank you

C:\Users\lanet>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.592], locale tr-TR)

```
• Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (3 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
• Engine revision e1e6ced81d
• Dart version 2.7.0
```

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)

```
• Android SDK at C:\Users\lanet\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
X Android license status unknown.
  Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)

```
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
• Dart plugin version 192.7761
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
```

[√] VS Code (version 1.42.1)

```
• VS Code at C:\Users\lanet\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.8.1
```

[!] Connected device

```
! No devices available
```

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

C:\Users\lanet>flutter doctor --android-licenses

Android sdkmanager tool not found (C:\Users\lanet\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).

Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,

visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51712

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51712 i found solution from this link i donwloaded commanlinetools only from androıd studıo websıte and ı dowloaded a zip file ı exratct to ıt to appdata/local/android/sdk file and restart andrıod studıo and go to sdk manager and u can see from here sdk tools download ıt too and restart andorıd studıo agaın wrıte your cmd flutter doctor --android-licenses and accept them all wıth 'y' ı fıgure out lıke that ı wısh u solved too.

Comment: So you did exactly what the error message told you to do "  Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
"

Answer (score 0):

1. Scroll down and Download Command line tools only from [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads).
2. Put your Downloaded file (tools) in this location:

   ```
   C:\Users\ABC\AppData\ABC\Android\Sdk
   ```
3. Close your android studio , and again open android studio. And check update.
4. Open command line and pass:

   ```
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
   ```
5. And press <kbd>y</kbd> for accept.
6. Run flutter doctor you should be good.